# how to open a .msg with outlook file using php/html

Tags: php, html

In out intranet I would like to store a list of template email to use in outlook.

```
<a href="Close.msg">Email Closure Template</a>
```

the following opens the email in the browser but is there away i can get it to open in outlook itself?

Comment: It depends of the configuration of the client. You can't force this using PHP. You can configure every computer to open .msg with Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the file to be downloaded instead of opened in browser. Then the user will be able to open it with outlook. But you can't force outlook to open this file.

In your `.htaccess` file you can add:

```
<Files *.msg>
    ForceType application/octet-stream
    Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</Files>
```